# Select elements by class using nth-of-type

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to use `nth-of-type` to set a gray background for every other `.time` and `.title` element (odd/even pattern).

```
 <div class="calendar">
     <div class="time">Gray Background</div>
     <div class="title">Gray Background</div>
     <div class="time">White Background</div>
     <div class="title">White Background</div>
     <div class="time">Gray BG</div>
     <div class="title">Gray BG</div>
     <div class="time">White Background </div>
     <div class="title">White Background</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Could you supply the css you're trying to use?

Comment: `nth-of-type` is an element selector - it won't work with classes

Comment: Are the classes really pertinent here? I don't think so.

Comment: @BoltClock now that you are here, do you have any idea when will the `:nth-match()` tree-structural pseudo-class will be supported? This will help with things like -- select the odd among the <div> elements that have class foo --

Comment: @Ricardo Ruiz: No idea. All I know is that the syntax is now part of :nth-child() instead of a separate pseudo-class, and that only Safari has implemented it so far.

Comment: I try also this one div>p:nth-of-type(odd){ background:gray; } div div:nth-of-type(odd){ background:gray; }

Comment: nth-child does work on classes. For example 
    :nth-child(4 of .my-class)

Answer (score 5):

The `nth-of-type()` pseudo class doesn't recognize classes. It only cares about *elements* that are children of the same parent ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo)).

Moreover, in this case, you don't need to match classes with `nth-of-type`.

Based on your HTML structure it looks like you want 2x2 zebra striping.

So, make every element gray, then override every 4th and 4th-1 with white:

```css
div > div {
   background-color: lightgray;
}

div > div:nth-child(4n),
div > div:nth-child(4n-1) {
   background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="time">Gray Background</div>
  <div class="title">Gray Background</div>
  <div class="time">White Background</div>
  <div class="title">White Background</div>
  <div class="time">Gray BG</div>
  <div class="title">Gray BG</div>
  <div class="time">White Background</div>
  <div class="title">White Background</div>
  <div class="time">Gray Background</div>
  <div class="title">Gray Background</div>
  <div class="time">White Background</div>
  <div class="title">White Background</div>
  <div class="time">Gray BG</div>
  <div class="title">Gray BG</div>
  <div class="time">White Background</div>
  <div class="title">White Background</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your variant better, I try also this one

 div>p:nth-of-type(odd){
  background:gray;
}
div div:nth-of-type(odd){
  background:gray;
}

Answer (score 0):

`:nth-of-type` matches by the elemnt name, not by the class.

> The [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has an+b-1 siblings with the same **element name** before it in the document tree-type

One way to fix it is to wrap `item` and `time` in an element, like this:

```css
.appointment:nth-of-type(odd){
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
    <div class="appointment">
        <div class="time">Gray Background</div>
        <div class="title">Gray Background</div>
    </div>
    <div class="appointment">
        <div class="time">White Background</div>
        <div class="title">White Background</div>
    </div>
    <div class="appointment">
        <div class="time">Gray Background</div>
        <div class="title">Gray Background</div>
    </div>
    <div class="appointment">
        <div class="time">White Background</div>
        <div class="title">White Background</div>
    </div>
</div>
```